# remove duplicate entries in cell - R

Tags: r

I searched high and low on here, as well as tried duplicate and unique functions for what I'm about to ask, but couldn't get anything to work.  Let's say I have a data frame named company with a variable state.  When I collapse the rows I'm left with this output in one of the state variable observations:

```
PA;PA;PA;TX;TX
```

How could I remove the dups inside the cell (and entire vector for that matter), so it looks as follows:

```
PA;TX
```

I have no problems removing dup rows, but can't seem to do it for the cells themselves.

Comment: Do you need to do this by row? Maybe provide an example of how your data frame actually looks like

Comment: What If the string is `PA;TX;PA;TX`?  Same thing?

Comment: Seems a better idea to remove the redundant rows from the original data frame.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for a single string:

```
x <- "PA;PA;PA;TX;TX"

x2 <- strsplit(x, ";")

x3 <- unlist(x2)

x4 <- unique(x3)

x5 <- paste(x4, collapse = ";")
```

If you want to do it for the whole vector `company$state`, you could roll all that up into one call to `sapply`:

```
sapply(company$state, function(x) paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(x, ";"))), collapse = ";"))
```

Comment: thanks ulfelder!  The first part works well, but when I try to apply it to the vector, I get the following error:   Error in strsplit(x, ";") : non-character argument.  Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: The non-character argument thing comes up when you try to run `strsplit` on something other than a string, like a data frame or matrix. Did you try the `sapply` version?

Comment: If you run `class(company$state)`, what's the result?

Comment: I get the following: [1] "factor"

Comment: Yeah, so that's the problem. Either turn that factor into a string before you run the call to `sapply`, or roll that step into the call to `sapply` with `strsplit(as.character(x), ";")`.

Comment: thanks, ulfelder!  Your solution works perfectly.  Though, this may sound like a simple question, but the sapply isn't actually changing my df, it just showing me the  results in the terminal.  What code would I need to add to get it to change the vector in the actual df? Probably a simple solution, but I can't get it to work and have never used sapply.

Comment: Just assign the result of that call to `sapply` to the column you want to overwrite, e.g., `company$state <- sapply(...`.