# Shiny: Join Cells in R

Tags: r

I would like to make this table:
[image: Input]
Look like this:
[image: Output]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please have a look at [ask] and try to provide a [mcve], and then edit your post accordingly.  In particular: (1) post data and code that can be copied, not images; (2) update your title - there's nothing about Shiny in your question (or update your question, if there should be); (3) show what you've already done - that will make it easier to give you specific help.

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr:

```
df <- tibble(id = c(1,1,3),
             b = c("foo", "bar", "foo"),
              c = c("x", "y", "z"))
df

# A tibble: 3 x 3
     id b     c    
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1 foo   x    
2     1 bar   y    
3     3 foo   z   

df %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  summarize(new = paste(b, collapse = ","),
            new2 = paste(c, collapse = ","))
```

which results in:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
      a new     new2 
  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>
1     1 foo,bar x,y  
2     3 foo     z
```

Comment: to be more specific to you examaple use:
`group_by(ID,Reviews, Class3) %>% summarize(Class1 = paste(Class1, collapse = ","), Class2 = paste(Class2, collapse=","))`

Comment: This worked. However, in Class 1, I expected `a,b,c ` but it resulted to `a,b,a,c`.

Comment: This solved my second issue. Thank you so much. [remove duplicate entries in cell - R] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40269101/12276902)

Comment: This solution is working only if id is `<dbl>`. This will fail if ID is string.